# What are the issues with regards to printing non-standard fonts in RDLC reports?

Tags: printing, fonts, rdlc

We use the Microsoft Report Viewer control in our web application to print checks.  The report needs to use a special MICR bank font in the report.  Something like this: http://www.micrfonts.com/

Anyways the font is just a regular TTF font installed in Windows.

Now, when testing the printing on my local setup, everything works perfectly.  The checks print on my personal LaserJet using the font correctly.

However, at my client's site, he is telling me that the font is rendering in the web-browser OK, which I think confirms that he has the proper font installed on his machine, but when he sends the report to the printer, the printout does not use the correct font.

Are there any limitations with the RDLC printing with regards to non-standard fonts?  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

More details that I just discovered:

Apparently, everything works from my PC if I connect to my local instance of the app on localhost.

However, if I connect to my app on our remote dev environment, I can replicate the issue of the font not properly printing.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Apparently the font needs to be installed both on the client, and on the webserver.

When rendering to screen, the report viewer uses Html, so the font needs to be on the client machine.  However, when printing, the report is generated server side before being sent to the printer, so in that case, the font needs to exist on the server, otherwise it will be substituted.

Took a while to find this.  Hope this helps someone else.